# remove alt+enter in excel while generating values

Tags: vba, excel, trim

I am having an end of line problem, can you guys tell me how to fix it? When I enter a value in excel and then do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then the values in that cell breaks and moves to next line. I wanted to make it in single line. Not sure how to do it.

For example right now I am getting output like this:

```
EnvName=testing  testing 
testing testing`
```

but the generated output should be like this:

```
EnvName=testing  testing testing testing
```

Providing my code below

```
Sub export()
  Dim i As Long


            Value = Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value
            'If InStr(1, Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value, " ") Then
            '  Value = """" & Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value & """"
            'End If

  Close 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you pick up a value from a cell on your sheet, if it might have a line break in it then you need to replace it, to avoid getting that same line break in your output:

```
Value = Replace(Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value, vbLf, "")
```

Not sure exactly what you'd want to replace the line break with: here I've used an empty string but you can use anything else.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you tell me which line should I need to replace, and can you explain your code so confusing, not sure what they will do

Comment: can you tell me how to print the values and see, like for js we use console.log and for java we use system.out.println, like that for vb??

Comment: `Debug.Print` will print to the **Immediate** pane in the VB editor

Comment: so I should use sth like this Debug.Print(Value) .... but to print it in my testing.txt file what code should I be using

Comment: I have one more problem when I give text in one cell its working fine, where as when I give numbers in another cell with enter scenario I am getting type mismatch error...any solutions will help me

Comment: Just make sure your Print calls are printing the substituted value and nor the "raw" cells value.  I don't see any problem with numbers in cells: you'll need to update your question to add your current code if you're having a specific issue.